# Migrating multiple Wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

We have 5+ Wordpress sites which we want to migrate to Google Cloud Platform. Can anyone please let me know if we need to create separate instances for each site or is it possible to move all Wordpress sites into a single instance?

Thanks
Prasun

Comment: Apache can support thousands of websites if the instance has enough resources. Wordpress is just an application that runs on Apache. There is not enough details in your question to provide a good answer. For example, traffic requirements, bandwidth, memory, disk, etc. Does each website require its own IP address or is virtual hosting sufficient. Are you concerned with security or isolation.

Comment: Hello, John,

Thanks for your answer. Currently we are using VPS server. We have average monthly bandwidth is around 5 GB with monthly traffic 1.5 GB. Our disk space usage is less than 10 GB and memory less than 2GB. We do not require different IP address for individual sites. If single instance is sufficient then can you please let me know how can we install multiple Wordpress sites on a single instance?

Comment: Google search. An answer to your question takes the space of an article. Look for articles like this one. However, start with the basics and learn how to configure Apache. Then look at WordPress: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-18-04/